# Cancel command in on_command event?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, discord, discord.py

i am adding a feature to my discord bot that will allow you to disable a command in a specific channel. Everything works perfectly besides the actual disabling the command part.

```
@bot.event
async def on_command(ctx):
    try:
        with open('serverdata.json', 'r') as f:
            data = json.load(f)

        await update_server_data(data, ctx.channel.guild)

        storage = data[f'{ctx.channel.guild.id}']["channels"][f'{ctx.channel.id}']["disabled_commands"]

        if str(ctx.command) in storage:
            await ctx.channel.send(f'{ctx.command} is disabled in this channel!')
            # somehow stop command from working
    except:
        pass
```

Is there some sort of built-in function for this or am i gonna have to use a different method? I would rather not have to add new code to every single command. All help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the command by writing an if statement in the command definition itself, the if statement can write a message to the user and will end the function with return.
Example:

```
@bot.command()
async def an_example_comand(ctx, *, some_parameters):
    if not command_allowed():
        await ctx.send("This command is not allowed in this channel.")
        return
    
    # Here should be the code to be executed if the command is allowed.


# The command_allowed() function should return a boolean.
# If it returns False then the command won't run.
```

Comment: Is there a way to cancel the commands from inside the on_command event? Or is that the only way

Comment: @chairiscute7 if you check the commands with if statements in the on_command event you can return too